# How to convert TaghelperContent to TagBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

How to convert TaghelperContent to TagBuilder?

For example, i have below taghelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("custom-tag")]
public class CustomTag: TagHelper
{
public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
var content = await output.GetChildContentAsync();
TagBuilder tag= content.??? // how to return as tagbuilder?
}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To convert TagHelperContent to TagBuilder, you can use the TagBuilder constructor and set its InnerHtml property with the content of the TagHelperContent. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("custom-tag")]
public class CustomTag : TagHelper
{
    public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var content = await output.GetChildContentAsync();

        // Convert TagHelperContent to TagBuilder
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder(output.TagName);
        tagBuilder.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(content);

        // You can set other attributes, classes, or styles if needed
        // tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(output.Attributes);

        // Replace the original output with the TagBuilder
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(tagBuilder);
    }
}
```

In this example, TagBuilder is instantiated with the tag name from output.TagName, and then the InnerHtml property is set with the content from TagHelperContent. Additionally, you can copy other attributes, classes, or styles from the original output if needed.